# Edge Chromium takes several seconds to load search results for one-word searches typed into address bar

Tags: windows, microsoft-edge

Typically, when I am looking for something on the Web, I will create a new tab, then, like most people, type my search terms directly into the address bar. This works fine when there are multiple search terms. However, when there is only one, Edge appends a slash to that term, then waits several seconds before displaying the results.

That might not sound like a big deal, but when you're doing dozens of searches every day, it gets really frustrating really fast.

There doesn't seem to be any way to change this in Edge's settings. I have noticed that sometimes, Edge displays "Waiting for assets.msn.com..." in the status bar during the delay. That turned up one suggestion on Google -- blocking that domain in the host file -- but that did not have any effect.

If I use the Search Box, then there is no delay, but the search engine that gets used is Bing and the Search Box does not have focus by default anyway.

I can also hit CTRL+E after creating a new tab, which then uses the default search engine (Google), again without any delay, but that is... extra work and should not be necessary in the first place.

The issue does not happen if I use, say, Firefox, but since I am on my work computer, that introduces other problems and running multiple browsers is not a solution either.

Does anyone know how to disable this annoying Edge behavior/feature?

Comment: Have you tried a different DNS provider? The slow load response is a symptom of another problem

Comment: This is on my work laptop and, while I could probably change the DNS server, I would prefer to avoid modifying my network settings if at all possible. A VPN is also involved.

Comment: So have you asked your system administrator for assistance? Any solution we might have liked would be difficult to implement as a non-elevated user on the domain

Comment: Tried adding a space?

Comment: @Tetsujin Tried it. It just gets trimmed off. :(

Comment: This feature (trying to access http://searchterm/ when trying to search for a single word) is meant to allow you to easily access intranet sites (that do not have a TLD like .com, and are instead managed by your company DNS server to route it to the correct site.) So given that a company and VPN are involved, this is likely something set by them intentionally.

Comment: Appreciate the info, you guys. I have created a ticket in our IT system and am waiting for them to get back to me.